# Heroku SSL security certificate not working: CNAME from Namecheap domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, cname

I am trying to set up a CNAME Record from my Namecheap domain to my Heroku app. I understand that Heroku offers a free SSL certificate if you use the default name rather than a custom domain. I am using a default name (example.herokuapp.com).

On Safari, I receive a "untrusted" popup and then it proceeds to load; on Firefox, I receive a connection untrusted:

`www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.herokuapp.com, herokuapp.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)`

And Chrome refuses the connection.

My Namecheap Advanced DNS is set up as follows:

`Type                | Host | Value                           | TTL   | 
CNAME Record        | www  | example.herokuapp.com           | 30 min|
URL Redirect Record | @    | http://www.example.com [Masked] |       |`

`heroku domains` looks like this:

`example Heroku Domain
example.herokuapp.com
example Custom Domains
Domain Name                    DNS Target

www.example.com  example.herokuapp.com
example.com      example.herokuapp.com`

Is there something I am doing wrong that is causing this problem? My goal is to have the user be able to load the page by going to example.com, www.example.com, http://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com, and https://www.example.com.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, Heroku only allow you to use their free SSL for the default `example.herokuapp.com`. You have to purchase your own SSL certificate if you want to use `https` for your own custom domain like `example.com` or `www.example.com`

Comment: I see; I misunderstood and thought that if I was directing from my custom domain to a default example.herokuapp.com, I could use the free SSL. This makes much more sense. I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: There are also a number of add-ons that you can subscribe to for your app that provide various levels of SSL protection for your site. You can find these in the add-ons section under security.